# flashlight not working on some devices

Tags: android, camera, led, flashlight

I currently made a simple flashlight app but it is not working on some devices with camera LED but on others it works fine. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Camera camera;
    private Camera.Parameters parameters;
    private ImageButton flashLightButton;
    boolean isFlashLightOn = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        flashLightButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.flashlight_button);
        flashLightButton.setOnClickListener(new FlashOnOffListener());

        if (isFlashSupported()) {
            camera = Camera.open();
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
        } else {
            showNoFlashAlert();
        }
    }



    private class FlashOnOffListener implements View.OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isFlashLightOn){
                flashLightButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_off);
                parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.stopPreview();
                isFlashLightOn = false;
            }else{
                flashLightButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_on);
                parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                camera.startPreview();
                isFlashLightOn = true;
            }

        }

    }

    private void showNoFlashAlert() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Your device hardware does not support flashlight!")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Error")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    private boolean isFlashSupported() {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(camera != null){
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that isn't working?

Comment: Also, maybe give some examples of devices it works on and some it doesn't work on?

Comment: i have shared the code have a look at this

Comment: it is not working on some devies of karbonn, samusung, lava,micromax,gionee and others with different android versions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having has to do with how certain manufacturers have different ways for putting their camera LED in flashlight mode and how some older devices running dated versions of android used to enable the LED. Samsung and HTC usually have issues, so the simplest way to go around this would be to use switch-case statements to turn the flashlight on/off for different types of devices. This question has been asked several times before so a good way to go about this would be to search on here for the different ways of turning on the flashlight for different manufacturers and android versions. Then write some logic that gets your device's attributes, tests them using switch-case or if-else and do what you're supposed to for each vendor. At least, that's the best way to ensure full compatibility.

Comment: can u tell me how can i do this #shahraiz. because i'm so begginer and don't know much about android